# Mysql Errors when add trigger - how will be right?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table BEFORE INSERT ON Users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 SET UserIdn = NEW.UserIdn;
    INSERT INTO Table2 SET UserIdn = NEW.UserIdn;
    INSERT INTO Table3 SET UserIdn = NEW.UserIdn;
    INSERT INTO Table4 SET UserIdn = NEW.UserIdn;
  END;
```

**We get error:**

```
Error
SQL Query:


CREATE TRIGGER Table  BEFORE INSERT ON `Users`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1 SET UserIdn = NEW.UserIdn;
Answer MySQL:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Tell me please where error and how will be right?

Comment: can you please change the name of the trigger because TABLE is reserved word

Comment: You need an `on` before the table name.  I'm not sure if this is causing the syntax error, though.

Comment: @IleshPatel name `Table` only for example.. could you please show me trigger on sqlfiddle with 4 insert ?

Comment: I add SQL Fiddle in the ans. Also I agree with StuartLC.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert syntax is wrong - you seem to have hybridized `insert` and `update`:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.UserIdn);
...
```

(Or if you wanted to update an existing row, then `UPDATE Table1 SET UserIDn = NEW.UserIDn WHERE ...`)

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6802/1)

Comment: error when i use `begin`, see please `
CREATE TRIGGER Users11 BEFORE INSERT ON Users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);
 
  END;
`

If i use Begin i get error in trigger..

Comment: make trigger with insert in tree tables when insert row on main table please

Comment: [Updated Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f31ea/1). Check that you are using [Delimiters correctly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sysntex is wrong,

For trigger ,
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

For Update,
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

For Insert data into table ,
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

For Insert data into table using select  ,
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: but i again get error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: see please `CREATE TRIGGER Users11 BEFORE INSERT ON Users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);
 
  END;`

If i use begin i get error in trigger

Comment: I tried to build schema in sql fiddle and it works fine.. where is the issue now?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER Users11 BEFORE INSERT ON Users 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);

Comment: could you please show me code trigger on sqlfidle with 4 insert (when in my example)?

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Users11 AFTER INSERT ON Users 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);
INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);
INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);
INSERT INTO Table1 (UserIdn) VALUES(NEW.ID);
END //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Works on my TOAD not sql fiddle... :(]

Answer (score 0):

```
create table demo(name varchar(30));
create table demo2 (name2 varchar(30));

CREATE TRIGGER demoinsert BEFORE INSERT ON demo
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO demo2 SET name2 = NEW.name;
    INSERT INTO demo2 SET name2 = NEW.name;
    INSERT INTO demo2 SET name2 = NEW.name;
    INSERT INTO demo2 SET name2 = NEW.name;
  END;
INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('a');

SELECT * FROM demo2
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77cf1/1)